# Calling one method from another method in Python

Tags: python, methods

I realize this code really makes no sense, but I am just practicing :)

Basically want I want to do is if the user enters a blank name for birthdays, I want it to jump to the savings loop and run through that code.

I am realizing though that the following is not correct:

```
self.savings()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}
while True:
    print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        self.savings()
    if name in birthdays:
        print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)
    else:
        print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
        print('What is their birthday?')
        bday = input()
        birthdays[name] = bday
        print('Birthday database is updated')


savings = {'401k': '100.00', 'RothIRA': '500.00', 'Savings': '350.00'}
while True:
    print('Enter an account: (blank to quit)')
    money = input()
    if money =='':
        break
    if money in savings:
        print((savings[money] + ' is the total amount in your ') + money)
    else:
        print('I do not have savings info for ' + money)
        print('How much money is in this account?')
        acct = input()
        savings[money] = acct
        print('Savings database is updated')

print(savings)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code doesn't define any functions or methods. I think you need to read about defining functions in your textbook or tutorial.

Comment: Use definitions?

Comment: @PM2Ring you are correct, I don't actually have any functions or methods.  Just 2 dictionary variables.  I wasn't looking at this clearly.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `self.savings()` in

```
if name == '':
    self.savings()
```

couldn't you you use `break` to leave the while loop immediately? And then it should move on to the next loop.

...I'm pretty sure that would work.